# Как восстановить аудиосистему в Fedora 36?

Tags: linux, аудио, fedora, pulseaudio

Я пытался подключить беспроводные наушники к компьютеру. Мои наушники поддерживают кодек LDAC, поэтому я выполнил инструкцию, описанную в [этой](https://kasunc.medium.com/enabling-ldac-codec-support-in-fedora-linux-for-bluetooth-headsets-66008e2287ae) статье, чтобы получить поддержку LDAC у себя в системе. После перезагрузки звук пропал полностью, не воспроизводился ни с колонок, ни с подключённых проводных наушников (и при запуске любого трека или видео ползунок "прогресса" стоял на месте). Причём система видит подключённые аудио устройства.

Скорее всего проблема в этой команде:

`sudo dnf install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth-freeworld --allowerasing`

Ведь на Fedora 36 используется pipewire...

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему.

Comment: Как проверить поддерживают ли наушники что-то?

Comment: @eri Не понял вопроса. Зачем это проверять?

Comment: Я не уверен что мои наушники это умеют

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне удалось решить проблему следующей командой:

`sudo dnf install pipewire-pulseaudio --allowerasing`

И последующей перезагрузкой.